# Hebrew regex match not working in php

Tags: php, regex

this is my current regex code to validate english  & numbers:

```
const CANONICAL_FMT = '[0-9a-z]{1,64}';

public static function isCanonical($str)
{
    return preg_match('/^(?:' . self::CANONICAL_FMT . ')$/', $str);

}
```

Pretty straight forward. Now i want to change that to validate only hebrew, underscore
and numbers. So i changed the code to:

```
public static function isCanonical($str)
{
    return preg_match('/^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]+|[\w]+)$/i', $str);

}
```

But it doesn't work. I basically took the hebrew UTF range out of Wikipedia.
What is Wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get it to work much more easily, using the `/u` flag and the  `\p{Hebrew}` [Unicode character property](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php):

```
return preg_match('/^(?:\p{Hebrew}+|\w+)$/iu', $str);
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/gSlmh

Comment: KObi, what's the beginning ?: stands for?

Comment: @Tom - nothing special - it is a [non-capturing group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group). I just copied it from the question `:)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want `preg_match()` to work properly with UTF-8, you might have to enable the [**`u` modifier**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) *(quoting)* :

> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is
>   incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8.

In your case, instead of using the following regex :

```
/^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]+|[\w]+)$/i
```

I suppose you'd be using :

```
/^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]+|[\w]+)$/iu
```

*(Note the additionnal `u` at the end)*

Comment: If it didn't work, can you provide what version of PHP and PCRE you're using? That information is in phpinfo(), and I ask because PCRE has been significant improvements in newer PHP versions.

Answer (score 1):

You need the /u modifier to add support for UTF-8.

Make sure you convert your hebrew input to UTF-8 if it's in some other codepage/character set.

Comment: i tried: $str = utf8_encode($str); and then:/^(?:[\u0590-\u05FF\uFB1D-\uFB40]+|[\w]+)$/iu   without any luck.

Comment: @Tom `utf8-encode()` encodes a ISO-8859-1 string, but that is not a hebrew character set. What is the incoming character set? Try `mb_convert_encoding()` with the proper character set. Is this data coming from a webpage? Because you would make you life a lot easier if you did utf-8 in the webpage, then you don't need conversions. Also, `\u0590` is not legal in preg. You need `\x{0590}`.